# Calc II: Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.

Tags: calculus

I've been working on with the area of the region in my calc II class, and now have to deal with the volume.

Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.
$$y = 7\sqrt{49 − x^2}, y = 0, x = 2, x = 3$$ about the x-axis

I was able to draw the graph, but can't set up the integral.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the disk method.

$$
\pi \int_2^3   \left(7\sqrt{49 - x^2}\right)^2 \ dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

The region you are rotating about the x-axis can be visualized as follows:
[image]

If you recall the disk method, the way we visualize finding the volume of the solid of revolution around the x-axis, is, we are essentially adding up infinitely thin disks of volume $dV$ for each small width $dx$ at each $x$ (a way to think of the integral). A disk at position $x$ will have radius equal to the distance from the x-axis to the curve, in this case $7\sqrt{49-x^2}$, and will have width $dx$, an infinitely small piece of length on the x-axis.
Therefore
$$ dV = \pi r^2 h = \pi (7\sqrt{49-x^2})^2 \, dx = 49\pi(49-x^2) \, dx $$
and so
\begin{align}
V &= 49\pi \int_2^3 (49-x^2) \, dx \\
&= 49\pi \left[ 49-x^2 \right]_2^3 \\
&= 49\pi \left[ 49x-\frac{x^3}{3} \right]_2^3 \\
&= 49\pi \left[ 49-\frac{19}{3} \right] \\
&= 49\pi \cdot \frac{128}{3} \\
&= \frac{6272\pi}{3}
\end{align}